# how to see array contents in gdb when passed from a function

Tags: c++, c, arrays, gcc, gdb

I would like to see the contens of my array when passed as an argument to a function, through gdb.

Say, I have some code which looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int b[], int len)
{ 
 int i = 0;

 /* how do I see the contents of array b[] in gdb */
 for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
     printf("%d ", b[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    fun(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));
    return 0;
}
```

In gdb, a[] looks as follows

```
(gdb) disp a
1: a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

But If I try to print b[], since it's a pointer (as array is passed as a pointer), the contents looks like this

```
fun (b=0x7fffffffdf90, len=5) at main.c:14
(gdb) disp b
2: b = (int *) 0x7fffffffdf90
```

I want to be able to see the contents of b[] just like I'm seeing a[] so it helps me debug.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where is the prototype of `fun()`?

Comment: Note that arrays are **not** pointers! They are most times implicitly _converted_ to a pointer, however.

Answer (score 5):

You may display using [artificial array](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html) as follow:

```
*b@len
```